# Setting z-index higher than parent

Tags: css, z-index

I have two divs which are `.navbar` and `.content`. `.navbar` is fixed, and `.content` overlays `.navbar` when scrolling.

JSFiddle demo is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7D77j/) Please make the result panel bigger, so it doesn't show mobile menu.

But when I open dropdown menu, it is hidden under `.content`. Even if I set higher z-index than `.content` on dropdown menu, it's not working. Is it just the way it works, or am I missing something? Is there any fix on that without modifying HTML?

UPDATE:

`.content` div should overlay `.navbar` div when scrolling exactly like the demo.

Answer (score 0):

just set z-index: 1 for `.content` and z-index: 2 for `.navbar`
http://jsfiddle.net/7D77j/1/

Comment: Thanks, but .navbar should be under .content when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
.content {
      z-index: 1;
}

.navbar {
     z-index: 2;
}
```

`.navbar` z-index is less than your `.content` z-index thats why dropdown is not coming above the content div

Comment: Thanks, but .navbar should be under .content when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this css:

```
.navbar{
    z-index:3;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/7D77j/2/

Comment: Thanks, but `.navbar` should be under `.content` when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

then you should remove the `.navbar-fixed-top` class and the padding on `body`
http://jsfiddle.net/7D77j/6/

Comment: Thanks, but `.content` should overlay `.navbar` exactly like the demo.